# Problems trying to install the plugin package

Tags: haskell

So I was going to try playing around with run time code reloading, and IIRC plugins was the way to go.

But on my msys terminal, the compilation fails. Is this a package bug or I'm missing a dependency?

My GHC is from the latest Haskell platform, 7.4.1.

Thanks in advance.

```
Mdx@Bhmt ~
$ cabal install plugins
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring plugins-1.5.2.3...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for ghc... ghc
checking for value of __GLASGOW_HASKELL__... 704
checking for ghc library directory... C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\20
12.2.0.0\lib
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for arc4random... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.mk
config.status: creating testsuite/makewith/io/TestIO.conf
config.status: creating testsuite/makewith/unsafeio/Unsafe.conf
config.status: creating config.h
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
Building plugins-1.5.2.3...
Preprocessing library plugins-1.5.2.3...
[ 1 of 12] Compiling System.Plugins.Process ( src\System\Plugins\Process.hs, dis
t\build\System\Plugins\Process.o )
[ 2 of 12] Compiling System.Plugins.Parser ( src\System\Plugins\Parser.hs, dist\
build\System\Plugins\Parser.o )
[ 3 of 12] Compiling System.Plugins.LoadTypes ( src\System\Plugins\LoadTypes.hs,
 dist\build\System\Plugins\LoadTypes.o )
[ 4 of 12] Compiling System.Plugins.Consts ( src\System\Plugins\Consts.hs, dist\
build\System\Plugins\Consts.o )

src\System\Plugins\Consts.hs:39:23:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character 'P'
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
plugins-1.5.2.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: installation here works just fine .. what ghc version are you using.. ?

Comment: > `checking for value of __GLASGOW_HASKELL__... 704`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `ghc` from `7.0.4` version.

Comment: Is the 7.4 in the package description 7.0.4 or 7.4.1?

Comment: I got that 7.4 as 741 and not 704! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Not correct: `For version x.y.z of GHC, the value of __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ is the integer xyy (if y is a single digit, then a leading zero is added, so for example in version 6.2 of GHC, __GLASGOW_HASKELL__== 602`